# Was this Phantasy Star Online cover ever used?

Tags: version-differences, phantasy-star-online

[*amazon.de*](http://www.amazon.de/Sega-Phantasy-Star-Online/dp/B00004YZHU/) lists the German version of **Phantasy Star Online** (for *Dreamcast*) with this cover:

[image: Phantasy Star Online cover (amazon.de)]

However, the only German version I know has this cover (which you can find on [*amazon.co.uk*](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Sega-Phantasy-Star-Online-Dreamcast/dp/B00004YZHU/)):

[image: Phantasy Star Online cover (amazon.co.uk)]

Was the *amazon.de* cover ever used? Maybe in the first/older edition? Or does it belong to a different localized version and *amazon.de* made a mistake? Or was an early draft and *amazon.de* didn't change it to the actual cover?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's placeholder artwork. The only place where you will find the artwork is in E3 trailers and posters. Not even the Network Trial Edition or Demos of the game use this cover.